# How to use a method multiple times in one?

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, methods, eleventy

**Objective:**

So I'm using Eleventy as an SSG and want to create multiple folders and copy some files into these folders, before Eleventy is doing the building or site generation.

A JSON file is for the array of site titles (folder names).

And I chose to make use the fs-extra module instead of the Node.js fs module.

**Inside .eleventy.js (config file):**

```
    const fse = require('fs-extra');
    const arrayFromJSON = require('./_data/sites.json');
    const arrayTitles = arrayFromJSON.titles;
    
      eleventyConfig.on("beforeBuild", () => {
  // Create site folders and copy layout and frontmatter data to the folders
    arrayTitles.forEach(element => 
      fse.copySync(`sitesource/index.njk`, `src/_sites/${element}/${element}.njk`, { recursive: true }));
    arrayTitles.forEach(element => 
      fse.copySync(`sitesource/fm.11tydata.js`, `src/_sites/${element}/${element}.11tydata.js`, { recursive: true }));
  });
```

I've been looking around for ideas and examples to combine these two actions into one, where it's only needed once to call *arrayTitles.forEach*. But I haven't found it.

***Is this possible, and anyone with suggestions to improve this code?***

Answer (score 0):

I may be confused, but why not simply use one forEach?

```
eleventyConfig.on("beforeBuild", () => {
    // Create site folders and copy layout and frontmatter data to the folders
    arrayTitles.forEach(element => 
      fse.copySync(`sitesource/index.njk`, `src/_sites/${element}/${element}.njk`, { recursive: true });
      fse.copySync(`sitesource/fm.11tydata.js`, `src/_sites/${element}/${element}.11tydata.js`, { recursive: true });
    );
  });
```

Comment: Yes, I have tried that... worked the same way. But in the end it gave me problems. The first build was no issue, but with the rebuilds it gave problens, hanging in an endless loop of rebuilding. Solved that problem runing this script with NPM from package.json.